# Can't find templatefile

Tags: go, beego

I have a beego project in IdeaProject. The structure is like this:

```
MathApp
├── conf
│   └── app.conf
├── main.go
├── main_test.go
└── views
    ├── invalid-route.html
    └── result.html
```

However, it shows the error `can't find templatefile in the path:views/result.html`. I have set the `gopath` as `C:/gopath`.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Please show content of result.html and also .go file which is calling this template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the code producing this error in [`template.go`](https://github.com/astaxie/beego/blob/7452151beec2f43c42122fd91b7523bcbccf05be/template.go#L52-L76)

[This issue](https://github.com/astaxie/beego/issues/1989) mentions:

> Please use the `bee run`, as `go get` install the binary into the `gopath/bin`, while the static file still in the `gopath/src/myproject`.